# Load Javascript on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load one of my advertisers javascript on a click event but I am getting errors from the javascript when it loads.

```
var get_ad_popup = function () {
    _adUnit= {settings: {siteID: 'T1446', pop: {type: 'popunder'}} };
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = "http://cdn.adunit.com/js/gp.min.js";
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        e.parentNode.insertBefore(s, e);
    })();
};
```

Then when I call the function I get this error in the console.

**TypeError: _adUnit.pop.clkPop is not a function**

If I look in the head I can see that the javascript was properly loaded. I just wondering why I get this error.

**Edited:**
If I load the javascript outside of the function and just include it in the head then it works just fine.

The script can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/QXTkz/

This is provided to me by my advertiser.

Comment: did you forget to define a function and store it in `_adUnit.pop.clkPop`? or is the advertiser code supposed to do that.

Comment: You are assigning a new object to _addUnit maybe you should just update a property? `_addUnit.settings = {siteID: 'T1446', pop: {type: 'popunder'}};` ?

Comment: I've updated the original questions. Thank you for the suggestions thus far.